# Which repair manual should I use for a 2006 E-150 transmission?

Tags: transmission, service-manual

This is a hobby project and I am aware that it's hard. Transmission repair is not covered in Haynes or Chilton manuals and transmission repair manuals are sold by the transmission model, not the vehicle model.

I don't know which manual to use because I am having a hard time identifying what transmission I have. There are many numbers on the side of the transmission and I don't know which one identifies the transmission itself. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5FYA4-vrLk) is a video walk around of the transmission. I think the part number for the transmission is one of these.

6C2P 7000 AA FFAQ (it might be 52CP. I can't really make it out), A4311220306, PKF-FA0, 6A 032436, RF-6 L 3P-7006

What manual should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2006 Ford Econoline (E-Series) Service Manual.

Since those manuals don't exist new anymore, I would just look on ebay for a paper copy or a "free" pdf online. There's a lot of rules to acquiring a free one legally so I am not going to point you to a random site, but you can find them fairly quickly with a google search.

The manufacturer service manuals give specific step-by-step instructions for all trim levels and transmissions and will give you the info to identify them.

Don't use Haynes/Chilton manuals, they are worthless. You are left guessing at a lot of stuff. Newer cars only have electronic versions of the manuals or pdfs. i.e. my Saab you had to acquire their WIS software which until they went out of business was impossible to purchase. Most companies aren't like that though.